# creating a new folder and a text file inside that folder

Tags: c#

I wanna create a new folder named `log` and inside that folder i want to create 
a textfile named `log.txt` and this is the path i want to create `D:\New Folder`

i have tried this to create a new folder named log

```
string FilePathSave = Folder.ToString() + System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\New Folder\Log");
```

And i have created a text file using this

```
string FilePathSave = Folder.ToString() +"log.txt";
File.WriteAllText(FilePathSave, TextBox1.Text);
```

But i cant create like `D:\New Folder\Log\log.txt`...any suggestion??

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Urm, something like this?

```
var dir = @"D:\New folder\log";  // folder location

Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

// use Path.Combine to combine 2 strings to a path
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "log.txt"), "blah blah, text");
```

Comment: The check for directory exists isn't really required, no? `Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they already exist` - MSDN definition of [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

```
    string dir = @"D:\New Folder\Log";
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    }

    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "log.txt"), TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using `Path.Combine` here:

```
string folder = Path.Combine(root, "log");
if(!Directory.Exists(folder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
string file = Path.Combine(folder, "log.txt");
File.WriteAllText(file, text);
```

Answer (score 4):

All the other answers to this question are correct. But I would like to point out that the **Directory.Exists isn't required**. Even if the directory already exist, no exception will be thrown by Directory.CreateDirectory. The code can be as simple as the following three lines.

```
const string Folder = @"C:\temp"
Directory.CreateDirectory(Folder);
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Folder, "log.txt"), "This is the test you want to write");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string d = "D:\\New Folder";  

if (!Directory.Exists)  
  Directory.CreateDirectory(d);

File.WriteAllText(d + "\\log.txt", textBox1.Text);
```

And add the using System.IO directive to your form.